# why esc_url not working in smartmetabox

Tags: metabox

Have you ever tried http://www.wproots.com/ultimate-guide-to-meta-boxes-in-wordpress/ ? It's good classes to create metabox. But I'm having problem with the validation.

I tried the `sanitize_callback` parameter to sanitize URL, so I used `esc_url` but the field still accepted all values. What is the problem here?

Here's my code

```
add_smart_meta_box( 'themename_slides_url', array(

    'title'     => __( 'Slides Options', 'themename' ),
    'pages'     => array( 'slides' ),
    'context'   => 'normal',
    'priority'  => 'high',
    'fields'    => array(
            array(
            'name' => __( 'Slides URL', 'themename' ),
            'id' => 'slide_url',
            'default' => '',
            'desc' => __( 'Type the URL of the slide', 'themename' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'themename_sanitize_url'
            ),
        )
    )

)


function themename_sanitize_url( $new, $meta_key, $id ) {

    if( esc_url( $new ) )
        return $new;

}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

`esc_url()` is not a validator. Use [PHP’s filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) for that.

Example:

```
// $url is now an URL or FALSE
$url = filter_var( 'http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL );

if ( $url )
    # update post meta
else
    # delete post meta
```